# How to import Jenetics Library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lib, jenetics

First post here, I hope it's not too dumb, but I tried for several hours and can't find a solution.

I want to play around with evolutionary algorithms and therefor tried to import the [Jenetics](http://jenetics.io/) Library.
I downloaded the zip and tried to import it into an existing java Project.

I'm working with eclipse and tried to add the zip(and later the two jar files inside the zip) this way:
Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs.

After that I tried to import something in my code (`import io.jenetics.BitGene;`) which couldn't be resolved.

The last time I had to import a library I added a jar-file, maybe that's the Problem, but I can't seem to find a right jar-file inside the zip

Thanks for the help

Comment: The README.md file explains that the download contains source code which can be built using gradle

Comment: let's try use the latest version from maven repository - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jenetics/jenetics/4.2.0
Add External JARs with the file you down from maven

Comment: Thanks for the help. The link from Hai solved the Problem, I could download and add a jar from there.